# Convert a Json response with X dictionaries inside a list into a readable csv

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to export a list of macros that I receive from a website into a csv.

The issue is that I have to run this script through x pages, each page has 100 results and every result has y number of actions.

The field 'actions' is a list that contains several dictionaries (different number in each result), from which I want to extract the first value to a column and the second value I want to be the data that goes below)

With this type of data:

```
{'id': 360011748819,
 'title': 'Macros de reenvío::Portugal::Fraude-Excellence',
 'actions': 
[{'field': 'status', 'value': 'open'},
  {'field': 'comment_value_html',
   'value': '<p>{{dc.macro-derivacion_fraude}}</p><p><br></p>'},
  {'field': 'current_tags', 'value': 'excellence derived_from_fraud'},
  {'field': 'group_id', 'value': '24905185'}]£
```

I'd like to achieve a csv that looks like this:

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCy04.png)

I've managed to write this:

```
for i in range (2):
        url = f'https://xxxx.zendesk.com/api/v2/macros.json?active=true;include_usage_24h;page={i+1}'
        r = requests.get(url, auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers).json()
        if len(r['macros']) == 0:
            break ##This breaks the loop if the page is empty
        else:
            for b in range (100):
                d = len(r['macros'][b]['actions'])
                lista += [str(r['macros'][b]['id']) + "`" + str(r['macros'][b]['title'])
                 + "`" + str(r['macros'][b]['restriction']) + "`" + str(list(r['macros'][b]['actions'][c].values()))
                 for c in range(d-1)]


ma = pd.DataFrame(lista)
ma.to_csv('accionesmacro.csv', index=False)
```

But the result in the csv looks like this:

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hkz9y.png)

Every action is created in a different line... I'm kind of desesperate and any help will be greatly appreaciated.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
lista = []
for i in range(1,3):
    url = f'https://xxxx.zendesk.com/api/v2/macros.json?active=true;include_usage_24h;page={i}'
    r = requests.get(url, auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers).json()
    if not r['macros']:
        break
    for b in r['macros']:
        actions = b['actions']
        row = [ b[field] for field in ('id', 'title', 'restriction ] + [ action['value'] for action in actions ]
        lista.append(row)
ma = pd.DataFrame(lista)
ma.to_csv('accionesmacro.csv', index=False)
```